# trying to get autocomplete working using knockout javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, data-binding, knockout.js, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete using Knockout, the autocomplete example is taken from: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

I'm trying to keep all JavaScript/knockout in a separate file, here's what it looks like thus far in Knockout file:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

this.counties = ko.observableArray([]);

this.getCounties = function () {
    self.counties([]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Search/ByCounty',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data && data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var obj = data[i];
                    self.counties.push(obj);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};

function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
    the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
    var currentFocus;
    /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
    inp.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
        var a, b, i, val = this.value;
        /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
        closeAllLists();
        if (!val) { return false; }
        currentFocus = -1;
        /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
        a = document.createElement("DIV");
        a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
        /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
        this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        /*for each item in the array...*/
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
            if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
                b = document.createElement("DIV");
                /*make the matching letters bold:*/
                b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
                b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
                b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                    inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                    /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                    (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                    closeAllLists();
                });
                a.appendChild(b);
            }
        }
    });
    /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
    inp.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
        if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
        if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
            increase the currentFocus variable:*/
            currentFocus++;
            /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 38) { //up
            /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
            decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
            currentFocus--;
            /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
            addActive(x);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
            e.preventDefault();
            if (currentFocus > -1) {
                /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
                if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
            }
        }
    });
    function addActive(x) {
        /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
        if (!x) return false;
        /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
        removeActive(x);
        if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
        if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
        /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
        x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }
    function removeActive(x) {
        /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
        }
    }
    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
        except the one passed as an argument:*/
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt !== x[i] && elmnt !== inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), self.counties());

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Using the above the ajax call that I call using the function getCounties is okay as this brings back my json and puts this into the array. However, the values then do not appear in autocomplete input in my view, no errors either. The html in my view is on a separate page like so:

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;" class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form autocomplete="off">
            <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
                <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCounty" placeholder="County">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="search('county')">Go</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess this line in my Knockout file must be incorrect?...Or my binding is off, somewhere?..

```
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), self.counties());
```

Answer (score 0):

Two minor mistakes:

1. `autocomplete` function should be called only after the ajax call is complete. Otherwise `self.counties()` would still be empty.
2. You never called `this.Counties()`. So I called it at the location where you had formerly called `autocomplete`.

```js
var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

this.counties = ko.observableArray([]);

this.getCounties = function () {
    self.counties([]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Search/ByCounty',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data && data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var obj = data[i];
                    self.counties.push(obj);
                }
            }
            autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), self.counties());
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};

function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
    ...
    });
    function addActive(x) {
        ...
    }
    function removeActive(x) {
        ...
    }
    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        ...
    }
    /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
    document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/

this.getCounties();

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top:10px;" class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form autocomplete="off">
            <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
                <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCounty" placeholder="County">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="search('county')">Go</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```